# Why do I receive NullReferenceException if I use a Nullable Entity Framework lazy-loading referenced field?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

Today I come across a very strange error. I have the following method:

```
    public IQueryable<AspNetUserDetails> GetDetails()
    {
        return this.Get()
            .Include(q => q.AspNetRoles)
            .OrderBy(q => q.UserName)
            .Select(q => new AspNetUserDetails()
            {
                AspNetUser = q,
                Roles = q.AspNetRoles,
                StoreAdmin = q.Store,
            });
    }
```

*(in the database, `AspNetUser` has `AdminStoreId` column that allows null, and is a foreign key to primary key of table `Store`)*

In my caller, I have this code to convert to ViewModel (it has the same field names as the Entity):

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<AspNetUserDetailsViewModel>> GetDetails()
    {
        return await this.BaseService.GetDetails()
            .ProjectTo<AspNetUserDetailsViewModel>(this.AutoMapperConfig)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

I recieved NullReferenceException at the `ProjectTo` method. The `ProjectTo` method is of AutoMapper, and the problem also happens if I use normal `Select` statement, so it has nothing to do with AutoMapper. I **have already solved** the problem by changing the Entity Select statement to this:

```
            .Select(q => new AspNetUserDetails()
            {
                AspNetUser = q,
                Roles = q.AspNetRoles,
                StoreAdmin = q.AdminStoreId == null ? null : q.Store,
            });
```

My question is: why? Shouldn't `q.Store` is already null if it has no reference?

Comment: Is AspNetUserDetails StoreAdmin property nullable too? Most probably it's not which is why you have to manually assign null if there is no q.Store

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado Yes, `AdminStoreId` iss Nullable `int` in the database. The property is generated by EF, so it is `int?` in the entity.

Comment: what does 'this.Get()' return?

Comment: It's `DbContext.AspNetUsers`, I am using Repository Pattern.

Comment: If you are sure that the model AspNetUserDetails StoreAdmin property is nullable, EF probably doesn't know that an AspNetUser has a 0 to 1 relationship with Store even if you defined the foreignkey as nullable. One way to solve this is to manually define relationships with the fluent API. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620) for more details.

Comment: The link you gave me is for Code First. My entities are generated by database first. Also, there is clearly a 1-n relationship between `AspNetUser` and `Store`, because there is that generated reference property `AspNetUser`.`Store` (and `Store` also has `AspNetUsers` collection).